Implementing Offline Updates for a Django REST Framework Project - Best Approach?
I'm building a Django REST Framework (DRF) application and am exploring ways to handle offline updates for my users. The goal is to allow users to access updated version of my project with a flash usb or something like that.
as my clients does not have any special technical knowledge(like how to pull a repo or even how to deploy a project on their servers) i need to provide an easy way to let them update and use latest features.
Now specifically, I'd like to know:

Best practices for implementing offline updates in a DRF project
Recommended libraries or frameworks to simplify this process
Tips for managing data synchronization and version control for
offline updates


can you share more information on the offline use case? for normal projects you might use something like Periodic Tasks in celery (https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), but accessing it via a USB drive might pose some unique challenges

well assume you are having a project for warehousing that lands on clients laptop and you added another feature to it. now you want to provide this update to your client but he is not a technical person. what would you do then?
